# Order of $10$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{25}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

From Prof. Pinter's "A Book of Abstract Algebra":

> What is the order of $10$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{25}$?

I know from the chapter, "Order of Group Elements," that the **order** is defined as:

> If there exists a nonzero integer $m$ such at $a_{m}=e$, then the **order** of the element $a$ is defined to be the **least positive integer** $n$ such that $a^{n}=e$. (where $e$ is the neutral element).

What binary operation must I use to figure out the order of $10$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{25}?$

Comment: They probably mean to use addition modulo $25$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are looking at the group of the integers mod $n$, it is (usually) implied that the binary operation is integer addition mod $n$. Working it out, this would mean that $10$ has order $5$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{25}$.

Answer (score 2):

You are in search for the smallest positive integer $j$ such that $10j \equiv 0 \ (\textrm{mod} \ 25)$.

$10$

$10 \cdot 2= 20$

$10 \cdot 3 = 30 = 25+ 5 \equiv 5 \ (\textrm{mod} \ 25)$

$10 \cdot 4 = 40 = 25+15 \equiv 15 \ (\textrm{mod} \ 25)$

$10 \cdot 5 = 50 = 25+25 \equiv 0 \ (\textrm{mod} \ 25)$